# Creating Multivariate Uniform Distribution in Julia

Tags: julia, distribution

I'm trying to create a multivariate distribution in Julia by combining multiple single variate distributions. I'd like to make a 10-dimensional distribution with each dimension varying from 0 to 10. I tried using the Distributions package and there is a `Product` function that seems to be what I need. However, the expected construction `Product(Uniform(0,10),10)` doesn't work. The example provided in the docs which is `Product(Uniform.(rand(10), 1))` seems to create a distribution by varying the lower bound of the uniform distribution, which isn't what I want.

Comment: You refer to this as multivariate, but you haven’t said anything about a correlation structure. Are the marginals independent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you want independent, since you tried to use `Product`, in this case do
`Product(fill(Uniform(0, 10), 10))`.